# R function Sink isn't redirecting messages or warnings to a file

Tags: r, redirect, sink

I am looking to redirect stderr and stdout messages to an output file. Here's what I tried:

```
sink("outputFile" ,type = c("output", "message"))
print("using print")
cat("using cat\n")
message("using message")
warning("using warning")
```

When I run this code, I still see "using message" and "using warning" in my R console, and it's not being redirected.

Is there a way to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file? I used this code to redirect my stderr to stdout, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

```
sink(stdout(), type = "message") # sink messages to stdout
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps, using something like this:

```
zz <- file("test.txt", open = "wt")
sink(zz ,type = "output")
sink(zz, type = "message")
print("using print")
cat("using cat\n")
message("using message")
warning("using warning")
#and to close connections
sink()
sink()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: this is not enough; the code for closing everything correctly is missing - and this part is not trivial...

Comment: I was still having trouble getting the warning to appear with this answer - I had to add an argument `warning("using warning", immediate. = T)` or change the global options with `options(warn=1)` in order to have the warning delivered immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is something missing to the previous answer: Both final "sink()" should be specifying the type of sink you close, and then close the file. In that way you fully close the connection.

```
zz <- file("test.txt", open = "wt")
sink(zz ,type = "output")
sink(zz, type = "message")
print("using print")
cat("using cat\n")
message("using message")
warning("using warning")
#and to close connections
sink(type="message")
sink(type="output")
close(zz)
```