# R: sink package (for making log files) no longer available?

Tags: r, logging, knitr, sink

I am using R version 3.6.0 and tried installing "sink" but it says it is no longer available.

Is this package no longer used? I am looking for a way of making log files for a .Rnw script which uses knitr.

I have seen that some people use just cat() and some use sink() and cat() together. What is the best recommended way of making log files in R? Is there an alternative to sink()?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure there was a package named `sink`? I could not find it in the CRAN archives.

Comment: There's a `R` function called  `sink` where you can save logs.

Comment: Ah of course, that was a silly, mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @patL, sink is not a package, it comes standard with {base}. Just use it, no packages need to be installed. :)

You can refer to the following questions about the sink() function and the help page for sink for some additional usage ideas.

- [R sink() message and output to same file - sanity check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120777/r-sink-message-and-output-to-same-file-sanity-check)
- [R function Sink isn't redirecting messages or warnings to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173020/r-function-sink-isnt-redirecting-messages-or-warnings-to-a-file?rq=1)